# get the range of sequence values in table column

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a list of value in my column. And want to query the range.
Eg. If values are 1,2,3,4,5,9,11,12,13,14,17,18,19

I want to display
1-5,9,11-14,17-19

Comment: Are you actually storing comma-separated list of values in your column, or they belong to different rows?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that each value is stored on a separate row, you can use some gaps-and-island technique here:

```
select case when min(val) <> max(val)
    then concat(min(val), '-', max(val))
    else min(val)
end val_range
from (select val, row_number() over(order by val) rn from mytable) t
group by val - rn
order by min(val)
```

The idea is to build groups of consecutive values by taking the difference between the value and an incrementing rank, which is computed using `row_number()` (available in MySQL 8.0):

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=85ee0d6fee712fae9553f5ae1aa4a971)**:

```
| val_range |
| :-------- |
| 1-5       |
| 9         |
| 11-14     |
| 17-19     |
```

In earlier versions, you can emulate `row_number()` with a correlated subquery, or a user variable. The second option goes like:

```
select case when min(val) <> max(val)
    then concat(min(val), '-', max(val))
    else min(val)
end val_range
from (select @rn := 0) x
cross join (
    select val, @rn := @rn + 1 rn 
    from (select val from mytable order by val) t
) t
group by val - rn
order by min(val)
```

Comment: As I try your query I'm getting an error for val_range. I'm using mysql 5.7.19

Comment: @Zen: as I mentioned, this solution requires MySQL 8.0. I updated my answer with an alternative for earlier versions.

Comment: @GMB It took me a while to learn the `rn - val` trick to find groups. It's quite useful.

Comment: @Zen . . . I'm surprised that the assignment of `rn` working in 5.17.19.  I think in that version, you should be using a subquery for the `order by`, and this happens to work because the table is read "in order".

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I am always unsure that we need to pre-order before using variables when a single table is involved. Do you have a documentation that specifies that?

Comment: @GMB Unfortunately, val_range is still showing token error. As i try it to works but wrong range. I'm talking about the second query.

Comment: @Zen: this seems to work fine, as you can see [in this MySQL 5.7.29 DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=064861ab8a4172859785ae49f0348c6a). Please make sure to run the query exactly as provided.

Comment: @GMB mine is displaying 1-2, 2-3,3-4, 4-5 and more than thousands of rows appear which is not the case i'm looking.  I noticed use MSQL 5.7.29 while mine is 5.7.19 a bit different

Comment: @Zen: ok, I went with Gordon Linoff's recommendation to pre-order the table before ranking. Does that last query in my answer works better for you? [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d68fa22ba5c0675adcf28288a047d4b1)

Comment: @GMB still getting same result.

Comment: @GMB . . . I don't know if there is documentation.  Somewhere around 5.6, you need a subquery with `group by`.  Somewhere around 5.7, you need a subquery with `order by`. The documentation cautions against this as early as 5.6:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: *In a SELECT statement, each select expression is evaluated only when sent to the client. This means that in a HAVING, GROUP BY, or ORDER BY clause, referring to a variable that is assigned a value in the select expression list does not work as expected*. That's largely good enough for me, although that's not very specific about using a pre-sorted derived table. Thank you!

Comment: @GMB . . . MySQL says nothing about derived tables preserving the ordering, as far as I know -- and the documentation is a bit off because I'm pretty sure variables work with `ORDER BY` in 5.6.  Happily, assignment of variables in `SELECT` statements is now deprecated, so the discussion is moot.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: yes... or will be moot once everyone has upgraded to 8.0...

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to other answers:

```
select dn.val as dnval, min(up.val) as upval 
from mytable up
join mytable dn
    on dn.val <= up.val
where not exists (select 1 from mytable a where a.val = up.val + 1)
  and not exists (select 1 from mytable b where b.val = dn.val - 1)
group by dn.val
order by dn.val;

1   5
9   9
11  14
17  19
```

Needless to say, but using an OLAP function like @GNB does, is orders of magnitude more efficient.

A short article on how to mimic OLAP functions in MySQL < 8 can be found at:

[mysql-row_number](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/)

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=22fe2514e6c90f877a41f2b8d15f8847)

EDIT:

If another dimension is introduced (in this case p), something like:

```
select dn.p, dn.val as dnval, min(up.val) as upval 
from mytable up
join mytable dn
    on dn.val <= up.val
    and dn.p = up.p
where not exists (select 1 from mytable a where a.val = up.val + 1 and a.p = up.p)
  and not exists (select 1 from mytable b where b.val = dn.val - 1 and b.p = dn.p)
group by dn.p, dn.val
order by dn.p, dn.val;
```

can be used, see [Fiddle2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3c5eb9069ab4cbc658ebc801ad96cfe2)

Comment: Sounds neat but i can't tell it works with my huge data. What if I wanted to add another filtering column.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by another filtering column, do you mean a column that is used as a partition for your sequence of numbers?

Comment: @Zen, I have extended the example, see edit. The larger your data set is, the more expensive the traditional SQL92 solution is going to be. As you can see mytable is referenced 4 times in the query, whereas it is only a matter of `row_number() over(partition by p order by val)`in GMB:s question.

Comment: I was trying to make a general question maybe i should be specific. I print cards using pos machine. Table sales has list of serial_no, pos_machine_no, and card_amount. I want to get the range of serial_no sold by a specific pos machine grouped by card_amount.

Comment: Ask another question. Make sure to include create table statements and insert statements with sample data that Illustrates the problem. Db<>fiddle is an excellent tool for tvat

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63775220/trying-to-get-column-values-as-range