# Trying to get column values as range

Tags: mysql

I'm using mysql5.7.19 to print cards using pos machine. Table sales has list of `serial_no`, `pos_machine_no`, and `card_amount`. I want to get the range of `serial_no` sold by a specific pos machine grouped by `card_amount`

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5deb2793e357cda003bb7553137778cf)

I wanted to get all the range for pos_no: ps1

The result I'm looking for is:

```
|range  | card_amt|pos_no|

|100-102|   10    | ps1  |

|107-109|   10    | ps1  |

|111    |   5     | ps1  |
```

Comment: Why does your first result is 100-103 ? You dont have a 102 in the source table. Are you using MySQL version >= 8 ? That would help a lot with the possibility of windows functions

Comment: @ThomasG sorry i mean to insert 102. now fixed it. I'm also using mysql5.7.19

Comment: What is the result if for example card_amount for 101 is changed to 3?

Comment: @Lennart It will appear in two separate rows for 100 and 102

Answer (score 0):

I assume that card_amt for 111 in your expected result should be 10. I adopted my answer from your previous query:

```
select dn.serial_no as dnval, min(up.serial_no) as upval, dn.card_amt, dn.pos_no  
from sales up
join sales dn
    on dn.serial_no <= up.serial_no
    and dn.pos_no = up.pos_no
    and dn.card_amt = up.card_amt
where not exists (
    select 1 from sales a 
    where a.serial_no = up.serial_no + 1 
    and a.pos_no = up.pos_no
    and a.card_amt = up.card_amt
)
and not exists (
    select 1 from sales b 
    where b.serial_no = dn.serial_no - 1 
    and b.pos_no = dn.pos_no
    and b.card_amt = dn.card_amt
)
group by dn.pos_no, dn.serial_no, dn.card_amt
order by dn.pos_no, dn.serial_no;
```

This [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=eaeecf4b3c9d4ca5ea26810940551416) is a slight modification of your fiddle

For DBMS that support window function (MySQL 8+ as an example), much neater and more performant SQL can be constructed.